# NSKeyedArchiver .plist appending problem

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nskeyedarchiver

**

1. I am getting data from a form into an array and trying to write that array into a .plist file using NSKeyedArchiver.
2. Writing is successful,however it overwrites to the previous data whenever I run the script.
3. How can I append the new data to .plist file instead of overwriting?

**

```
@implementation Player

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

- (IBAction)savePlayer:(id)sender {
    NSString *path = @"/Users/username/fm.plist";
    NSString *pl= [teamPlayer stringValue];
    NSString *name = [namePlayer stringValue];
    NSString *age = [agePlayer stringValue];
    NSString *position= [positionPlayer stringValue];
    Player *player = [[Player alloc] init];

    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:pl,
                                  name, age, position, nil];

    [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:array toFile:path];
    NSString *ns = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:path];
    NSLog(@"test: %@" , ns);
    [array release];
}
```

—

```
- (void) encodeWithCoder: (NSCoder *) coder{
    [coder encodeObject:array forKey:@"someArray"];
}

- (void) decodeWithCoder: (NSCoder *) coder{
    [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"someArray"];
    return self;
}
```

Comment: I forgot to add the error I receive: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the last two methods don't seem to be relevant as you aren't encoding whichever object those methods belong to. Again, the `NSCoding` protocol includes `encodeWithCoder:` and `initWithCoder:` methods. There is no `decodeWithCoder:` method in the `NSCoding` protocol.

Secondly, you are creating a new `NSMutableArray` object initialized with few elements and archiving it to a file so it writes over the existing one. You will need to get the existing array through unarchiving the file, create a mutable copy and then appending the values. So code will be something like this,

```
NSArray *existingValues = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:path];
NSArray *newValues = [existingValues copy];
[newValues addObjectsFromArray:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:pl, name, age, position, nil]];
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:newValues toFile:path];
[newValues release];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this method looks inefficient. Every time, user enter data from a form, it needs to copy and than write the total object.

Comment: If you are thinking about storing form data, you should really look at Core Data. This one is definitely inefficient for such things.

Comment: If you are doing this often enough that you need to worry about the efficiency, you should keep a mutable version of the structure in memory and modify and write that each time. Or you should use a different storage system, like Core Data. You can't append to an on-disk plist; the format doesn't allow it.

Comment: Thanks Deepak!
I noticed that my error was using decodeWithCoder while there is no such method and I should have used initWithCoder instead.